# SQL to Linq conversion with SYSDATETIMEOFFSET

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, linq

Could someone assist me in converting following sql query to LINQ? Important part of this one is to be able to convert the date to a UTC date (with daylight savings).

```
SELECT      a.id, b.id
FROM        A a
join        B b on a.id=b.id
WHERE       DATEADD(minute, abs(DATEPART(TZ, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() at time zone b.TimeZone)), a.created_date) >= @some_utc_date
```

Comment: please, provide data example

Comment: Have you looked at `Ef.Functions.AtTimeZone` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.attimezone?view=efcore-8.0  Why is the date and the timezone in two different columns anyway?

Comment: might be eazyer to have additional datetimeoffset type column with included timezone before use linq?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866311/how-to-cast-datetime-to-datetimeoffset

Comment: `Ef.Functions.AtTimeZone` actually solved my problem, by doing this:
`EF.Functions.AtTimeZone(EF.Functions.AtTimeZone(a.created_date, b.TimeZone), 'UTC')`

Answer (score 1):

`Ef.Functions.AtTimeZone` actually solved my problem, by doing this:

```
SELECT      a.id, b.id
FROM        A a
join        B b on a.id=b.id
WHERE       EF.Functions.AtTimeZone(EF.Functions.AtTimeZone(a.created_date, b.TimeZone), 'UTC') >= @some_utc_date
```